# WP Site in subdirectory Joomla! Site - Permalinks not working

Tags: permalinks, htaccess

I have WordPress in a test folder inside the root directory where I Joomla! 3.x site is running. Somehow the Joomla! rewrite rules are interfering with the WordPress permalinks rules. I keep on getting Joomla! 404 messages and some odd:

```
file_get_contents(url) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in /path/to/file.php on line 16
```

errors. I try to resolve these specific errors [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17626612/wordpress-site-error-failed-to-open-stream-http-request-failed-http-1-1-404-no) on StackOverflow.

Is there a way I can make Joomla! only worry about Joomla! pages and make WordPress have its permalinks work again? I have not been able to come up with a rewrite rule or condition that works thus far. I tried the one mentioned [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14337/cannot-access-wordpress-install-on-subdirectory-of-drupal-site) as well. I used

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^foldername
```

which I added to the Joomla! .htaccess file just below the line where it says `RewriteEngine On`

No luck so far..

**Update**

See answer below. It was a faulty WP .htacces after all. Once it was correct is started working and ignoring the Joomla! .htaccess.

Comment: This would probably be a question for a joomla! answers site, as you are looking to change the filters and code of the way joomla! functions, and not wordpress.

Comment: Yeah, this question could have been asked at the Joomla! forum as well, but as the Joomla! site was doing OK and the WordPress site had issues I decided to ask here.  Anyways, as shown in my answer I figured it out more or less by now. And it seems that the correct WP .htaccess was just as important.

Comment: Fair enough. I will remove my downvote when possible seeing as wordpress was the cuplrit.

Comment: Thanks, I think you can just upvote it to even things out.

Comment: It wanted me to wait 12 minutes to change the vote xD lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that with the extra rewrite rule added to the Joomla! .htaccess file and with the corrected WordPress .htaccess file - wrong paths - the site started working again. I removed the Joomla! rewrite rule to ignore the WP folder and WP seems to be able to stand on its own now.